# Get the index of columns of table if the column text found in different tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we find the index of columns satisfying below tables ?  Some text are in `<th>` directly, some are in `<a>` tag and some are in `<div>`

```html
      <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Text 1</th>
          <th>Text 2</th>
          <th>Text 3</th>
        </tr>
        
    </thead>    
//Another table:
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>
            <a>Text 1</a>
            </th>
            <th>
            <a>Text 2</a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

 //Another table:       
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>
            <div>Text 1</div>
            </th>
            <th>
            <div>Text 2</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

I have tried below, but this is not complete yet,  how can we handle all in single line of code ?

```
let columnName = "Text 1" ;
const rowText1 = $('#tableID').find('thead').find(`tr:has(a:contains(${columnName}))`).index();
const rowText2 = $('#tableID').find('thead').find(`tr:has(th:contains(${columnName}))`).index();
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `.text()` to just get the text in the element.

Comment: Sorry, in my case I am passing column header text ie <th> to find the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `$('#tableID thead tr th:contains('+columnName+')').index();` it will return the index you are looking for.

Instead of `.find()` use **jQuery descendant selector** that find your tag under all decendents.

here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vahida/s9djkLta/6/).

Notice I have switched column **Text 2** in each table and it returns the correct index.

Comment: ..This worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the selector to search everything with `contains`:

```js
$(() => {
  const rowText1 = $('#tableID').find('tr:has(:contains("Text 2"))').index();
  console.log(rowText1) // Index would be 1
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableID">
  <thead>
       <tr></tr>
       <tr>
          <th>Text 1</th>
          <th>Text 2</th>
          <th>Text 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry I have tried, but not working if I gave second column data....

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  var needle = "Text 1";
  var stack = [];
  $("table > thead > tr").each(function(i, el) {
    $("th", el).each(function(j, cell) {
      if ($(cell).text().trim().indexOf(needle) > -1) {
        stack.push({
          table: i,
          col: j
        });
      }
    });
  });
  console.log("Needles Found", stack);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Text 1</th>
      <th>Text 2</th>
      <th>Text 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <a>Text 1</a>
      </th>
      <th>
        <a>Text 2</a>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div>Text 1</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>Text 2</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Iterating each table, and each header cell, we can seek out the table and column.